# Spark DataFrame Value update

Tags: pyspark

Just starting on an AWS Glue to check if certain column *CASE_STATUS_ID* has value 3 if yes, then change that to 2 and so on. Here is the dynamicFrame code:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = 
"etl_database", table_name = "case_data", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
```

If you can point me in a direction to check the current value and update it to the desired value using an *if* or *case* structure that would be really appreciated.